# joined four tables and the result was correct after joining fifth table appears the duplicacy and wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining five tables:

1. deliveries_shipped
2. delivery
3. carton
4. customer
5. requirement

after joining last table to get quantity column, giving duplicate rows?
I executed this query

```
SELECT c.carton_id, 
       c.delivery_id, 
       weight, 
       c.datetime_stamp, 
       carton_dim, 
       tracking_number, 
       ship_date, 
       d.customer_id, 
       status, 
       packer, 
       purchase_order_number, 
       customer_name1, 
       street_address, 
       cus.city, 
       city2, 
       country_code 
FROM   carton AS c 
       INNER JOIN deliveries_shipped AS ds 
               ON c.carton_id = ds.carton_id 
                  AND c.delivery_id = ds.delivery_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery AS d 
               ON d.delivery_id = c.delivery_id 
       INNER JOIN customer AS cus 
               ON cus.delivery_id = c.delivery_id 
WHERE  c.delivery_id = '0097301587';
```

here three rows for carton_id is coming and for that three carton Id the quantity `5000,1000,1000` how to get that?

Comment: Add sample data and expected output!

Comment: Can you provide you table structure with records

Comment: In your query you haven't joined the `requirement` table. Whatever attribute(s) you are joining on are not unique in the `requirement` table. You'll need to either add attributes to the join conditions, or decide which of the 'duplicates' you want (or perhaps sum the value from `requirement`.